# Singleton with readonly parameters

Tags: c#

The goal is to create a Singleton and pass it a parameter that is required for the construction and initialization of the class, then preventing any changes to be made to the passed parameter (just like a readonly field being set by an argument passed to a constructor).

For instance:

- Sockets
- Hosts
- Databases
- Repositories
- (Any instance that requires at least one argument in order to construct)

> I am having a tough time coming to terms with this design, and I am quite certain that there is a pitfall or a loose-end to this implementation of a Singleton combined with a Builder Pattern, to mimic readonly fields set by constructor arguments.

---

### Example Implementation

In this example, I am trying to get a Singleton of `Host`, where I would like the `enum EnvironmentTypes` to be treated like a `readonly` field usually found in classes that have parameters passed into the constructor.

**EnvironmentTypes Enum**

```
public enum EnvironmentTypes
{
    Production,
    Staging,
    Development
}
```

**IHost Interface**

```
public interface IHost
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Host Class**

```
public sealed class Host : IHost
{
    #region Singleton
    private static readonly Lazy<Host> _instance = new Lazy<Host>(() => new Host());
    public static Host Instance { get { return _instance.Value; } }
    #endregion

    private static bool _isInstantiated;
    private static EnvironmentTypes _environment;
    private string _name;

    internal static EnvironmentTypes Environment
    {
        get { return _environment; }
        internal set
        {
            if (_isInstantiated) throw new InvalidOperationException(nameof(_environment) +" cannot be set once an instance is created."); 

            _environment = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    static Host()
    {
        _isInstantiated = false;
        _environment = EnvironmentTypes.Production;
    }

    private Host()
    {
        _isInstantiated = true;
        _name = "My Server";
    }
}
```

**HostBuilder Class**

```
public sealed class HostBuilder
{
    private readonly EnvironmentTypes _environment;
    private string _name;

    public HostBuilder(EnvironmentTypes environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }

    public HostBuilder SetName(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public IHost Build()
    {
        Host.Environment = _environment;
        Host host = Host.Instance;
        host.Name = _name;

        return host;
    }
}
```

**Implementation**

```
class Foo
{   
    void UsingTheBuilder()
    {
        // probably over-kill
        HostBuilder builder = new HostBuilder(EnvironmentTypes.Development)
            .SetName("Bingo");

        IHost host = builder.Build();

        //host.Environment is not available, great!
        host.Name = "Renamed Server"; // works as expected.
    }

    void ManualConfiguration()
    {
        Host.Environment = EnvironmentTypes.Development;
        Host host = Host.Instance;
        host.Name = "Bingo";

        Host.Environment = EnvironmentTypes.Staging; // throws! Hoped to prevent
                                                     // the developer from doing this.
    }
}
```

*Random Notes: It would be great if I could restrict access from getting to the static properties of `Host`, so that I can totally avoid anyone trying to set the `Host.Environment` static property and throwing an exception -- note how the `HostBuilder` shields that from happening as it is a `readonly` field.*

Comment: Is there any reason why `Environment` can't be an instance property and also accessed via the `Instance`?

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. You want to be able to set it once before the singleton is initialized and prevent subsequent changes.

Comment: @t3chb0t - Right, exactly. I am trying to make it feel like a readonly parameter would. At least from the developer's point of view.

Comment: Where do you get the actual value for the environment from? Is it a database or app.config or how does the application know which environment it runs in?

Comment: I usually use an app.config where I have a setting called `Environment` and set it there.

Comment: @t3chb0t - I updated the question to illustrate that it is meant as a somewhat generic question towards Singletons that need readonly-like parameters.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your builder's `Build` method can only be called once because the second call will throw an exception when `Environment` is set again. Is that intentional?

Comment: @eurotrash - That's exactly the kind of pitfall / loose-end I was hoping someone would catch while reviewing. Thank you!  -- This feeling is like finding the itchy spot you've been searching for forever. Ahh!

Comment: Good luck unit-testing this.

Comment: @NikitaB - Could you explain why? Nothing stands out with regards to unit testing.

Comment: @Svek apart from all the problems that normally come with parameter-less singletons, how would you test different `EnvironmentTypes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am biased towards singletons. I think it is an anti-pattern, that has no place in modern C#.

First, here is a [great article](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/) on how singletons become a disaster when you try to unit test a code, that heavily relies on them. Your case is even more complex, because you also have to initialize additional parameters. And you can't change those. So you can't test `Host` with different "environments" unless you try to bypass your own exception with reflection.

I would just register non-static `Host` class as singleton inside IoC container, and be done with it. It will solve all your problems:

1. Parameters of `Host` are no longer exposed.
2. Container guaranties, that there is going to be a single instance of `Host`.
3. Host is exposed as service (`IHost`) and not as implementation (`Host`).
4. You can mock `IHost` in unit tests.
5. You can easily unit-test `Host` implementation with whatever parameters you want, because now it has public constructor and can be re-created as often as it is required by your tests.
6. Classes that depend on `IHost` will now require it as dependency, instead of secretly accessing it via global static property.